# Why is the IF statement seeing a FALSE when a value is TRUE?

Tags: php

I'm making login system, so when someone had signed up it will create automatically a row for him in database, the columns are (status, user name, user id),automatically the row of the user will be filled, status = 1, user name = the name of user etc ,and i put if user status was 1 it must shows a default image that i put it directly,and it shows as i want,

but if he press a button to change his image and he insert a new one the status must become 0 and must replace the new image into the default image,so the user status became 0 and all the database had been filled and the default image had gone as i want, but the new image(that had been inserted) don't show up, i don't know why,

until i close the if statement of `if($image_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress))` and then put else after it (so it became false not true) then write `echo "<img src='files/status/0/".$_SESSION['file_new_name']."' width= '500px' height='300px'>";` but when do that, everything is work and i don't see any error in database and in page, why that happen i don't understand?

and i don't want that, i need `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to be true not false

here the new image (not default) will not appear:

```php
if($image_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress)) {
  $stat = $image_row['STATUS'];

  $user_name = $image_row['user_name'];
  $user_id = $image_row['user_id'];

  $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

  if($image_row['STATUS'] === 1) {
    echo "<img src='files/status/1/default.png' width='500px' height='300px'>";
  }else {
    echo "<img src='files/status/0/'".$_SESSION['file_new_name'].">";
  }
}
```

but if i change and close `$image_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress)` after closing `if ($state === 1)`, so `$image_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress)` will be false and i don't want that, but the newer image appear,but i don't understand this, i mean in that method it shows no error even when i signed up and login it shows the default image and status =1 so when that happen `$image_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress)` must be true but when i press the button `$image_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress)` became false by itself and it shows me the new image that had been selected and the status of user became 0 without any error, i don't understand this :

```php
if($image_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress)) {
  $stat = $image_row['STATUS'];

  $user_name = $image_row['user_name'];
  $user_id = $image_row['user_id'];

  $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

  if($image_row['STATUS'] === 1) {
    echo "<img src='files/status/1/default.png' width='500px' height='300px'>";
  }
}
else
{
  echo "<img src='files/status/0/'".$_SESSION['file_new_name'].">";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a quick look to what your said. I think you don't understand what mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress) should do.

`mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress)` takes one row from the last result from the executed MySQL query and returns an associative array with one or more values depending on your query and never is just TRUE.

It returns FALSE if there are no more rows in the result left to fetch.

```
$image_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ress); // get the row as array

if ($image_row) {
// check if there was a row left to fetch
  $stat = $image_row['STATUS'];
  $user_name = $image_row['user_name'];
  $user_id = $image_row['user_id'];
  $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
  if ($stat == true) {
    // check if status is true (or 1 or "1") 
    echo "<img src='files/status/1/default.png' width='500px' height='300px'>";
  } else {
    echo "<img src='files/status/0/'" . $_SESSION['file_new_name'] . ">";
  }
}
```

Comment: yes i know that but as i said that if i press the button that upload an image, it's change the status of user from 1 to 0 on the database  , so it must be able to get a row to fetch, so i think it must be true, but it's going to be false,

Comment: First I would suggest you don't put the fetch it in an if statement but fetch once before and then check the contents of the row. Also you have an if statement with `=== 1` meaning it's a strict comparison. This means 1 must be of type integer and cannot accept a string "1" or true. Use `==` to allow it to test for 1 or '1' or true

Comment: why do you put "user_name", "user_id" and "STATUS" into a variable first when you don't reuse those variables? `$_SESSION['user_name'] = $image_row['user_name'];`does the same in one step and I guess you will thereafter always refer to `$_SESSION['user_name']`.

Comment: then if it answered your question mark it as answered ✅  and good luck with the rest of your coding

Comment: oh, that because it's easier to write a $state than $image_row['user_name'] because it's shorter, it's useless but i prefer to do it

Comment: oh thanks by focusing in your answer, you made me understand the reason behind this, thanks again

Comment: Hint: for the future on Stackoverflow, write a better Question description "the images don't appear, but in a method it appears, but i want it appear in method 1" would better be "Why is the IF statement seeing a FALSE when a value is TRUE"?

Comment: furthermore if you want the check value to be an integer you can do it like this `$stat = intval($image_row['STATUS']);` and thereafter the test `if($stat === 1)` would work. This might be useful if you plan to have more STATUS options like 2, 3 or more in the future.

Comment: oh, it's my first question, so i don't know how to write a convenient title, and about integer, i guess i don't need that because the status has two values: 0 and 1. but i guess it will be helpful later.